# FIBA Shot Clock reset on throw-in touching ring

Tags: basketball, fiba

I was going over a sample Q&A for a next level refs exam coming up. An answer stated the shot clock is reset to 14 secs after touching the ring.
It cited Art 29.  Which has this rule.

> Article 29.2.3. After the ball has touched the ring of the opponents’
>   basket, the shot clock shall be reset to
>     24 seconds, if the opposing team gains control of the ball.
>     14 seconds, if the team which regains control of the ball is the same team that was in control of the ball before the ball touched the ring.

However, during previous exam I recall the FIBA official interpretations using this exact scenario as an example.

> 17-20 Example: With 5 seconds remaining on the shot clock during the
>   throw-in A1 passes the ball towards the basket where it touches the
>   ring.
>   **Interpretation:** The shot clock operator shall not reset his
>   clock, as the game clock has not started yet. The shot clock shall be
>   started simultaneously with the game clock when the first player on
>   the playing court touches the ball.

I would not reset the clock.  And plan to raise this with the committee.

**Is there another section in the FIBA 2017 rules that supports the no reset as shot clock hasnt started view?**
The interpretation should be based on an article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing explicit in any rule to support this interpretation. However, Article 49 requires that

> The timer shall measure  playing time  as follows:
>
> Starting the game clock when:
>
> ...
>
> - During a throw-in, the ball touches or  is legally touched by a player on the playing court.

Since the ball is not in play when it first touches the ring, an argument can be made that it should not be included as a circumstance for Article 29.2 to be applied.

This is however a very weak argument, and without a statement from FIBA such as that in the Official Interpretations document, it would otherwise be ignored.

Comment: I think arguing you can not reset the shot clock if the game clock isnt running is the best point. Indeed I have seen a clock have this restriction  physically inbuilt which causes an issue if the game clock operator is slower to react that the shot clock operator.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few situations covered by the [FIBA rules](http://www.fiba.basketball/OBR2017/yellowblue/Final.pdf). If it's just a throw-in with no extra info added, then the shot clock will start simultaneously with the game clock as defined in §50.1 (merely because the game clock is restarted under the same conditions):

> Shot clock operator: Duties
>
> 50.1 Started or restarted when:
>
> - On  the  playing  court  a  team  gains  control  of  a  live  ball.  After  that,  the  mere  touching of the ball by an opponent does not
>     start a new shot clock period if the same team remains in control of
>     the ball.
> - **On a throw-in, the ball touches or is legally touched by any player on the playing court.**

With 5 secs remaining this scenario also may apply:

> 50.6 **Switched off**, after the ball becomes dead and the game clock has been stopped in any period when there is a new control of the ball
>   for either team and there are fewer than 14 seconds on the game clock.